# Publishing HTML5 advert using Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: html, adobe, ads, adobe-edge

**Background**

I am interested in learning how to make HTML5 web adverts which might be delivered to a website using an Ad Server.

I am capable of writing some JS using a library such as Move.js to animate my banners but I have been experimenting with Adobe Edge Animate in order to speed up the creation.

**Question**

What are the best settings to use to publish web adverts from edge animate?

Is it wise to use the Adobe CDN option if you are submitting to an Ad Server? If the CDN option is not used, the edge.js file is included locally and takes up an additional 100Kb, which is too much.

In addition, I have seen in the iab. guidelines that an html5 ad may be up to 100Kb in size - what are the realistic sizes that designers achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Can't answer animation questions but I run the ad server for a large publisher.

Recently I've had some Adobe Edge zips sent to me.  What should've been a simple process became tricky due to some of the ad server's limitations..

Re: including common files locally, please don't!  Ads are usually served so they deliberately don't cache.  Please use a CDN.  We get charged overage fees for large files, and my finance director moans at me if there's overage fees in last month's ad serving bills.

Re: file sizes, we are often charged overage fees for any ad creatives beyond a certain file size.  In reality I do wave through things larger than 100kb if it seems reasonable (or if there's video involved), but if I get a simple 300x250 ad with no discernable reason why it's 200kb, then I will reject it.  I can get away with the odd overage charge on those AOL bills..

Some general advice now:

re: making things clickable, please make the ad clickable yourself, and include a variable within the index.html loader file that handles the click URL.  Clearly label it too.  Ad servers allow us to dynamically insert click URLs along with a redirect that lets us count the clicks.  We do need to count these.

Re: Uploading files in folders - the ad server I use, ADTECH (provided by AOL) allows you to upload a zip folder containing all files.  But crucially, anything in subfolders won't be accessible..  (At least my experiments lead me to believe this, happy to be corrected!).  I had to reupload all the images & JS to root level, and then change all the file locations manually.  This is easy for your average Stackflower to do, but quite often the people setting these ads up in an ad server don't have any HTML/JS/FTP skills.

Answer (score 0):

Your AdServer should have templates with click and API integrated, so you do fast your Ads.

Also, you can use CDN libraries, make sure you use secure protocol (neve http://, use better http:// or just //)

In terms of weight, if depends it you are making and standard or a richmedia Ad. You can do it with Adobe Edge Animate but there are other options not so heavy (pure html5, GoogleWebDesigner, etc.)